# Unhandled Exception while running .exe on mono framework in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: mono

I am using ubuntu 13.04, I installed mono-3.1.2 on Ubuntu-13.04 successfully.
Now i am trying to run C# .exe from windows visual studio.

```
     $ mono WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
```

I am getting the following :-

```
                   Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal (IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal (IntPtr hdc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How to remove this exception , please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a solution but i am not sure that it is good practice.
I ran the following command
          $ find /usr -name libgdiplus.so
But I didn't found any file.
So I installed libgdiplus
           $ sudo apt-get install libgdiplus

After that again
           $ find /usr -name libgdiplus.so
             /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so
Then i simply copied libgdiplus.so in /usr/local/lib.
           $ mono WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

And i got expected output.
Is it good solution?
Or if any other suggestion is there please share .

Comment: You're mixing mono from sources with mono from packages, and it will bite you in the ass. Please read http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @knocte pointed out, you should

- Install Mono via apt-get such as `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`, so that libgdiplus is installed as well,
- Or compile both libgdiplus and Mono from source code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right. But I want to compile latest version of mono. Mono-complete will installed the which is latest in ubuntu relese.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem on Fedora 23 by installing `libgdiplus-devel` as follows:

```
dnf install libgdiplus-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

raffamaiden's answer worked for me, but there's a small spelling mistake in the answer:

```
dnf install libgdiplus-devel
```